# In JavaFX is it possible to get control of a window from another window, in real time?

Tags: java, javafx

Suppose, I run two windows simultaneously, the first one having a Textfield and a Button and the second one has a Label. If I write something in the Textfield and click the Button then the text will be shown in the Label (not open a new window, just change the label-text of the second window).

Comment: basically, you need a model that's known and listened to in all relevant parts of ui: then a change in that model will automatically update the ui state everywhere

Comment: You can also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/51050736#51050736) for an example.